# How to use multiple if else conditions using ternary operator in jsonpath- plus?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonpath, jsonpath-plus

**JSON**

```
{
   "customer":{
      "address":{
         "stateRegion":"",
         "stateRegionCode":""
      }
   }
}
```

**Code**

```
"address.state_code": "$.customer.address.[stateRegion ? stateRegion: stateRegionCode?stateRegionCode: null]",
```

Here in the above expression , I want `stateRegion` as the value if it is present in customer as parent object and address as a child object , else I want `stateRegionCode` and if both are not present I want `null`, how can we customize this thing using [jsonpath-plus](https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/docs/ts/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this during the initial creation of the object because accessing the object's properties (for use in your conditional expression) requires that the object already exists.

Maybe the closest you can get is, once you've defined the object, to write something similar to your `"address.state_code": "$.customer.address.[stateRegion ? stateRegion: stateRegionCode?stateRegionCode: null]"`:

```js
const
  $ = { "customer" : { "address" : { "stateRegion" : "", "stateRegionCode" : "" } } },
  {stateRegion, stateRegionCode} = $.customer.address; // Destructures address
$.customer.address.state_code = stateRegion
  ? stateRegion
  : stateRegionCode
    ? stateRegionCode
    : null;

console.log($.customer.address);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but my question was something different i was asking in json-path plus syntax , can we use ternary operator for multiple if else conditions?

Comment: Okay, sure. I added the jsonpath tag to the question for clarity.